# ¿Cómo verificar elementos de una página sin cargar su contenido en el navegador?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

¿Es posible analizar el contenido de una página sin tener que cargarla en el navegador?

He estado investigando y no encuentro nada parecido por internet, no se si sea posible, pero considero que sería genial poder analizar el contenido de un sitio web sin la necesidad de abrirlo o cargar los datos en el navegador (con tan solo copiar el url).

Tengo el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```js
function Analizar() {
 //Optengo el URL
 let value = $("#enlace").val();
  
 let listaDeIframe = AnalizarURL(value);
  
 //Mustro la lista...
 listaDeIframe.forEach(iframe => {
  $("#lista").append('<tr><td>' + iframe + '</td></tr >');
 });
 
 return false;
}

//Ejemplo
function AnalizarURL(value) {
 //Lógica aquí...
 return ["www.youtube.com", "facebook.com", "stackoverflow.com"];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return Analizar()">
 <div class="formulario">
  <input id="enlace" type="text" placeholder="Enlace a analizar" name="l">
  <button>Analizar</button>
 </div>
</form>
<table id="lista">
 <tr>
  <th>URLs</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Lo que intento hacer es obtener los atributos **src** de los elementos ***<iframe>*** de cualquier sitio web por medio de la función `analizarURl(value)` y crear una lista con estos valores.

> Algo parecido a la función de **JDonwloader**, que analiza los elementos de una página web por medio de un **url**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Si no tienes problemas en usar otros lenguajes, puedes hacerlo con PHP y el comando curl. Afinándolo un poco te funcionará con los https también.

Comment: Trabajo con ASP.NET puedo marcar como mejor respuesta si haces un ejemplo con esta tecnologia, o con JavaScript si es posible por medio de algun framework o paquete.

Comment: Olvídate. Con JavaScript no vas a poder hacer nada salvo que estén en la misma red o que el servidor este preparado para darte la petición. Con PHP solo en aquellos que no sean https, lo cual deja pocas opciones. Te puedo decir dónde coger el código, que lo hice yo, y lo pruebas cambiando la URL. Biblioteca digital del patrimonio iberoamericano, entra en su web, búscalo tal cual en Google, y bájate su "API". Abre el código y echa un vistazo, solo es un archivo PHP con el curl. Cambia la URL y me cuentas.

Answer (score 1):

Se podría hacer mediante un metodo `ajax()`.

`$.ajax({ url: 'urlQueQuieres', success: function(data) { alert(data); } });`

Esto funcionara siempre que la url forme parte del dominio desde el que se le llama (por motivos de seguridad). Esto quiere decir que lo que planteas **NO** se puede hacer.

La única forma de que esto funcione es que el servidor al que apuntas coopere (que tenga codificada una forma de responder a tu peticion; un Json, un header...)

Comment: Me pregunto ¿Cómo hace JDownloader para analizar los elementos de una URL copiada?, Estoy intentando algo parecido.

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero entiendo que es porque las url usadas en JDownloader apuntan a un recurso pensado para poder descargarse y por tanto permite ese tipo de interacción